# How to build a Module or Plugin Based Application

Tags: .net, architecture, plugins

Where can I find information on building a Module Based or Plugin Based (not sure which si correct) application?

Example - Say I have a productiion application and and I want to add a shipping module. Basically my users can click "Add Module" from my application and select a CAB or Zipped file and my shipping module can then be added to the app.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've got the .net tag, I'm assuming you're looking at implementing this app in .net. Take a look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are targeting Silverlight or WPF, take a look at [the PRISM framework](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF).

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface that all the plugins must implement.  Upon app startup or a user initiated process (uploading a file), discover which plugins are available and adhere to the interface.

Use [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).  Your app discovering what modules are available is preferred over defining the available modules via configuration files.